# Point $z_0$ where $z_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(z_n + \frac{a}{z_n})$ converges

Tags: complex-analysis, recurrence-relations

Let $a \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ be a complex number. Let
$$z_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(z_n + \frac{a}{z_n}), \ \ \ \ \ \ n \geq 0$$
For which $z_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ should I choose so $(z_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converges?
This problem looks quite similar to $z_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(z_n + \frac{1}{z_n})$. Here, $z_0 = x_0 + iy_0$ needs to be chosen such that $x_0 > 0$ or $x_0 < 0$.

I consider $w_{n+1} = \frac{z_{n+1} - 1}{z_{n+1} + 1}$. So,
$$\frac{z_n^2 - 2z_n + a}{z_n^2 + 2z_n + a}$$
But this doesn't look as nice as when $z_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(z_n + \frac{1}{z_n})$. Any suggestion how I should tackle this problem?

I also thought maybe I should consider $w_{n+1} = \frac{z_{n+1} - a}{z_{n+1} + a}$, but this gives me
$$\frac{z_n^2 - 2az_n + a}{z_n^2 + 2az_n + a}.$$

Comment: If $b$ is a square root of $a$ and $w_n=z_n/b$ this reduces to
$$w_{n+1}=\frac12\left(w_n+\frac1{w_n}\right)$$
that is the $a=1$ case.

Comment: @AnginaSeng This means that $z_0$ must have the same condition as in the case when $z_{n+1} = 1/2(z_n + z_n^{-1})$ (so $x_0 > 0$ or $x_0< 0$) but $z_n$ converges to a different limit. I believe they will converge to $\pm\sqrt{a}$. Correct?

Comment: That's ${\tt Newton}$-${\tt Rapson}$ for the $square\ root$.